# jQuery: read and access inline CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdata

I'm looking for a better solution, **to read CDATA with Javascript** (or a DOM-Utility like jQuery). It seems not to be possible, to access CDATA with javascript directly.

Here's my snippet, but it's quite ugly for my opinion:

```
<div id="becks" data-my-favorite="<![CDATA[ I like <br>German beer and busty woman]]>"></div>

var text = $('#becks').data('myFavorite').split('<![CDATA[')[1], 
    text = text.split(']]>')[0];

    log(text) // "I like 
                  German beer and busty woman"
```

Comment: (a) `.data('my-favourite')` is closer to what you want; (b) you can't have CDATA within attribute values, can you? (They're usually declared as CDATA or PCDATA or an option set, at least in SGML-based HTML. No idea what happens in HTML5.)

Comment: `<div id="becks" data-my-favorite="<![CDATA[...]]>"></div>` is not even valid HTML. I suggest you fix that instead of trying to find a way around it by bending jQuery.

Comment: Of course, `<div id="becks" data-my-favorite="<![CDATA[...]]>"></div>` is valid HTML5 !

Answer (score 0):

How about instead re-framing the problem to avoid including HTML entities in your data attribute?

```
<div id="becks" data-my-favorite="I like\nGerman beer and busty woman"></div>

var text = $('#becks').attr('data-my-favorite').replace('\n','<br />');
```